# Redux reducers: map or not map on editing

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I´m trying to figure out if I shouyld map or not in my reducer.

Here´s the context.

I have a redux state composed by...

```
friends [{}, {}]
pets [{}, {}]
users [{}, {}]
```

3 of them are array of objects based on GET responses (local API)

Here´s an example of one object of the friends array.

```
{
  id: '982347646324',
  name: 'Peter',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  age: 40
}
```

So... Now let´s say that I want to edit this entry.

My current reducer case would be...

```
...
      case EDIT_FRIEND:
      return state.map(el => {
        if (el.id === action.payload.data.id) {
          return {
            ...el,
            name: action.payload.data.name,
            lastName: action.payload.data.lastName,
            age: action.payload.data.age
          }
        }
        return el
      });
...

      default:
      return state;
```

Since I´m new and in the learning process, I should ask: 
Is this the right way to do it...? 
It works, yes, but I want to learn and do it properly.

Should I do it in other way...? 
Should I map or not...? Any help will be really helpful.

Thnanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, the map method which you use is one such and it is perfectly fine to use it. The other solution is using `spread syntax` and updating the desired object like

```
...
  case EDIT_FRIEND: {
      const index = state.findIndex(obj => obj.id === action.payload.data.id);
      return [
         ...state.slice(0, index),
         {
            ...state[index],
            name: action.payload.data.name,
            lastName: action.payload.data.lastName,
            age: action.payload.data.age
          }
          ...state.slice(index + 1)
      ]
 }
 ...

 default:
   return state;
```

You can opt to go for any of the solution that you find comfortable from the above two. What you must keep in mind is that you are not directly mutating the store state.

Answer (score 0):

Things you should not do in a reducer

1. make it impure
2. mutate the state

Since you are using map method, it will return a new array everytime and doesn't mutate your earlier array. So, it is totally fine to use map.